# batch job for auto folder creation with random name

Tags: batch-file

I am new to scripting, can some please assist me,

I would like to create a batch file that

1-        Looks at the first 8 characters in the file name, creates and moves those files to new folder with first 8 characters as folder name.

2-        Then looks at folder created in step 1 for next four series of character (9,10,11,12)and create and move to another subfolder with next 4 characters as folder name.

3-        Then looks at folder created in step 2, for extension of every file and create and move to a new folder with extension as folder name.

For example, I have files that look like this

ABCEFGHI0703xyz.pdf

STUVWXYZ0805xyz.pptx

Move to folder

ABCEFGHI\0703\PDF

STUVWXYZ\0805\PPTX

Keeping in mind first 8 characters are random, next 4 character are year and month, and 9 types of extensions.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Abdul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=c:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=c:\destdir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*" '
 ) DO (
 SET name=%%~na
 SET ext=%%~xa
 SET name=!name:~0,8!\!name:~8,4!\!ext:~1!
 ECHO MD "%destdir%\!name!"
 ECHO MOVE "%sourcedir%\%%a" "%destdir%\!name!\"
)
GOTO :EOF
```

---

Modified `MD` and `MOVE`command to suit destination directory required.

Comment: Ite will simply `ECHO` the names of the directories to be created and the `MOVE` command to be executed. After testing and verification, remove the `ECHO` keyword on the `MD` and `MOVE` lines to activate. Setting your source and destination directories is also required. Since the `MD` command will attaempt to re-create existing directories, append a ` 2>nul` to the `MD` line to suppress the (harmless) error report. Equally, the `MOVE` will report that one file was moved. To suppress that message, append ` >nul` to the `MOVE` line.

Comment: One issue with this code is when it creates new folders, it creates in the root directory now the actual folder, unless first 8 characters match the main folder name.
This works

Where source directory in batch file is set to C:\ ABCDEFG

File name ABCDEFG07031234.xls

1-        Result is C:\ ABCDEFG\ ABCDEFG\0703\XLS\ ABCDEFG07031234.xls

Creates folders within main folder, however when the source directory is C:\test

2-        Result is C:\ ABCDEFG\0703\XLS\ ABCDEFG07031234.xls

I would like to have second result not the first.

Answer (score 1):

Test this on a folder of files:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*.*) do (
   set "filespec=%%a"
   set "ext=%%~xa"
   md "!filespec:~0,8!\!filespec:~8,4!\!ext:~1!" 2>nul
   move "%%a" "!filespec:~0,8!\!filespec:~8,4!\!ext:~1!" >nul
)
```

Comment: Thank you,

That works how do I run the script in a particular folder  (s), rather than copying the script to each and every folder.

Regards,

Abdul

Comment: Also another issue with this script is extensions are not always 3 characters.

Comment: To run the batch file in different folders, place the batch file in a folder that is on the path, such as c:\windows.  I also modified it to use any extension.  If you need to run it in an entire folder tree then state that in your question to start with.

Answer (score 0):

there is a method to create random folders:

write into new batch file:

```
:start
md c:\Users\...\%random%
goto start
```

This will start creating random folders, you can create up to 36833 folders.

Comment: Attention! this is an endless loop.